# Project is working fine in one hosting server but when another, CSS, and jQuery file are not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting

I'm currently working on a student information system. I have tested it on the localhost as well as on a free Webhosting server, but when I upload it on another web hosting server, the site shows its contents only but all of the CSS and jQuery files are not working as expected.

The CSS and jQuery files are in the assets folder outside the application folder.

Webserver directory :
[image: webserver directory]

The base URL code is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'tmhs';
$root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

Comment: is the server an apache server? how does your `.htaccess` look like? you might need to set `RewriteCond`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the url directly

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.example.com/path_to_ci_folder";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base_url config should have no problems, I also use it like in all my projects.

```
$root = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

for css calls like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('assets/css/style.min.css')?>">
```